# php - hide certain products for certain users

Tags: php

I want to hide some products for some users, I have products table and users table .

for example , 
I have:

```
product a
product b
product c
product d
```

...

```
user 1  
user 2
user 3
user 4
```

...

1. case 1, I want user 1 and user 4 not see product a, meanwhile, other users can see.
2. case 2, I want user 5 not see product c, while other users can see.

One thing I know is I can add a `hide_status` row in the product table, set to 1 hide this product but this is global, meaning all user cant see.

Or I make a group and user in this group can't see product a, if I have 100 products, so I make 100 group?

I want to know how will the logic goes and how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you should create basic groups, and then assign them to users......then in product table, add column to show for which  usergroup.. it is easiest way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new table with association users -> products

1) Users table:

```
UserId Name...
1      Jhon
```

Products table:

```
ProductId Name ...
1         SomeProduct
```

2) HideProducts table

```
Id UserID ProductID
1    1       1
```

and you can assign any quantity of products to any user

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me , i have one question , when i display product how can know which user cant see this product , in your example , how can I not let userID 1 not see ProductID 1 ?

Comment: SELECT FROM HideProducts WHERE userId = 1 AND productID = 1, if query return rows, product should be hidden, but it's not really good for performance so it's better to  join this table

Answer (score 0):

If users are not going to see some products based on roles or groups they belong to,  you will have to put the `group_id` or `role_id` on the users table also on the product table. In this case since multiple groups may also not see a product you can use a comma separated list of ids so you don't need to create a whole new table.

Users table

```
id     name     group_id
```

Product table

```
id     name     group_ids
                1,2,3
```

Now in your code when listing products for user check if user group_id is in product group_ids otherwise skip.

```
for ($i=0;$i<count(products);$i++){

    if(!in_array($userGroupId, explode(",",$products[i]['group_ids']))) continue;

    //display product for user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `status` in `Users` table and also `Product` table. then add same status in users and product table's column what you want to hide.

then, use condition `SELECT * FROM Product WHERE User.status!=Product.status`

Example:: if `user1`, `user3` and `product3` all are status is 2 then `user1` and user3 can't show `product3`

Answer (score 0):

Create one more table & add reference of product & user table in newly created third table, So you can easily get which user has access to view which product.

I hope this will resolve your problem.